# About the geometry of the set of weights that is strongly linked to $\lambda$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, root-systems, weights

Define $\eta\uparrow\lambda$ if $\eta=\lambda$ or $\eta=s_\alpha\cdot\lambda<\lambda$ for some $\alpha\in\Phi^+$. More generally, $\eta\uparrow\lambda$ if $\eta=\lambda$ or $\eta=s_{\alpha_1}s_{\alpha_2}\cdots s_{\alpha_r}\cdot\lambda\uparrow s_{\alpha_2}\cdots s_{\alpha_r}\cdot\lambda
\uparrow \cdots \uparrow s_{\alpha_r}\lambda\uparrow\lambda$ for some $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_r\in\Phi^+$.

> Let $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ and $X(\lambda)$={$\eta$$\in\mathfrak{h}^*$$:\eta\uparrow\lambda\}$.
>
> I would like to ask whether there is any geometry about $X(\lambda)$ or the convex hull of $X(\lambda)$.

Comment: Can one make this more concrete in type $A_n$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is dominant, the convex hull of $X(\lambda)$ is the convex hull of $W(\lambda)$, i.e., a so-called $W$-permutohedron. Is this the kind of thing you are interested in?

Comment: More generally (that is, for $\lambda$ not necessarily dominant) in Type A I believe these convex hulls have been studied by Tsukerman and Williams under the name "Bruhat interval polytopes"; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5202.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I am interested in them. By the way, is there any references for the fact: If $\lambda$ is dominant, the convex hull of $X(\lambda)$ is the convex hull of  $W(\lambda)$?

Comment: Isn't this (that the up arrow relation is the same as (strong) Bruhat order) exactly what your previous question was about?: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338226/partial-ordering-on-mathfrakh-and-bruhat-ordering/338230

Comment: Do you mean $W(\lambda)=\{w\cdot\lambda:w\in W\}$, where $w\cdot\lambda=w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho$? Otherwise it seems nontrivial to me since the references does not use the dot action.

Comment: The dot action part is a distraction, imo: that just has to do with replacing $\lambda$ by $\lambda-\rho$. Can't you still show by the same argument that for antidominant, regular $\lambda$, $s_{\alpha}w\lambda \uparrow w\lambda$ if and only if $s_{\alpha}w < w$?

Comment: @Sam: Shouldn't your symbol $<$ be $>$ since $\lambda$ is regular *antidominant*?

Comment: I might be getting dominant and antidominant mixed up, yes.

Comment: I think Sam Hopkins is correct according to Humphreys' book (Section 5.2, p. 95) and the errata: http://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/bgg.pdf. Did I miss something?

Comment: @James:  I can't follow this reference to p. 95 of my book along with the errata.    More details?   The rationale for anchoring weights at an antidominant one is partly the $\rho$-shift but is mostly formal and helps later on in the treatment of "blocks" in $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: According to the errata, one has $w'\cdot\lambda\uparrow w\cdot\lambda\iff w'\le w$, where $\lambda$ is antidominant, integral and regular. Taking $w'=s_\alpha w$, we get $(s_\alpha w)\cdot\lambda\uparrow w\cdot\lambda\iff s_\alpha w< w$ since $s_\alpha w\neq w$.

Comment: Also, by your argument in section 5.2, we have $(s_\alpha w)\cdot\lambda< w\cdot\lambda\iff s_\alpha w< w$. This is the same as $s_\alpha \cdot(w\cdot\lambda)< w\cdot\lambda\iff s_\alpha w< w$. By definition of Strong linkage, $s_\alpha \cdot(w\cdot\lambda)< w\cdot\lambda$ is equivalent to $s_\alpha \cdot(w\cdot\lambda)\uparrow w\cdot\lambda$. Therefore, $(s_\alpha w)\cdot\lambda\uparrow w\cdot\lambda\iff s_\alpha w< w$. From either ways, we get $<$ instead of $>$.

Comment: @James Cheung:  Thanks for the clear explanation!  (Con.cerning your question about convex hull, this may go back to work of Kostant, somewhere in his many papers.    I'll try to check.)

Comment: @LSpice:  Please disregard my comment, which was too hasty.    As James Cheung has explained, what you wrote originally was accurate.